# Managing Java dependencies in a Grails application?

Tags: java, maven-2, grails, groovy, dependency-management

I'm trying to adopt my development from `Spring/Maven2/Tomcat -> Grails`, and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to manage dependencies in grails separate from maven. Maven does a lot of the magic that grails is doing automatically (unit testing/building/etc.), so I wonder if there's a need for maven at all in grails projects.

So, then, how do Grails users generally manage java dependencies? I've become accustomed to central repository dependency management, and I can't turn back at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails supports Maven to an extent but it's much more convenient to use Ivy. See the docs here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7%20Dependency%20Resolution

Comment: Pure dependency management is all I need, and it looks like Ivy can connect to the maven remote/local repositories for management, so I can plug this right in to my existing setup.